# Estimate affine transformation matrix based on another image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I know little about computer vision and I'm trying to find a way to keep an image at the same perspective of its projection (obtained by a camera). The ideia is to get an image (a) and, using the image of its projection (b), do an affine transform to obtain (c). I'm using opencv's ORB algorithm to do a feature matching and then evaluate the transformation matrix. The problem is that it doesn't work with symmetric figures (like a square).

How can I solve for the general case? Any other suggestions that don't use algorithms like ORB are welcome.

[Example of the described process for a square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqO5t.png)

Ps 1: The projection image (b) may have noise, as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqO5t.png).

Ps 2: I'm using only images with one channel (grayscale).

Comment: There's a lot of questions similar to this on Stackoverflow. Take your time, go through some older posts, or add the code and sample images that reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: I just saw similar questions with complex images, which is easier to estimate the transformation matrix. Maybe, I need to use something other than a feature matching algorithm like ORB.